# How can I interact with the page before loading?

Tags: python, selenium

I have encountered a problem using selenium with python. I'm trying to interact with a page like this:

```
driver_window_manager.get(url)
iframe = driver_window_manager.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
driver_window_manager.switch_to_frame(iframe)
```

But in the WebPage, a popup appears and waiting for the user to click AND THEN the page finally loads.

But `driver.get` in selenium waits for the page to be fully load, so i can't close this popup and interact with the page.

Thank you everyone and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blocking behaviour you describe is because of the default [page load strategy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/) in Selenium.  You can alter this via the desiredCapabilities or options class for your chosen browser.

```
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = ieOptions();
ieOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

`driver.get` waits for the page to be loaded and then only proceeds further, if you don't want to wait, then you need to use javascript to load the URL with [`execute_script`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#execute_script). It returns immediately so that you can perform any actions you want -

```
driver.execute_script("window.open(your_url);")
```

Now, if you want to, for example accept a popup, you can do -

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()
```

Note, you need to add the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: execute script doesnt work it returns me a "unknown error" :ile "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Is that normal that driver.execute_script("window.open(your_url)") works but its blocking my code until the page is loaded ..

Comment: @vandaelemathias you need to add a ";" at the end of js command. I have updated the code, try that and tell me what happens